# Compare levels of variables

Tags: compare

Is there a way to compare levels of variables in a dataset to another dataset, in order to check whether the coding has changed? Looking for a way to do this in either R or Python. Thank you!

Edit: I am looking for a way to look for differences in the coding of a dataset (i.e., the levels of variables/values the variable can take - are they reported differently) over time. I would like to do this in either Python or R. I hope this clarifies. It is not about the number of variables or the code that might differ in R or Python, instead, I want to look at all shared variables across different versions of a dataset and compare their unique values ("levels of variable").

Comment: What do you mean by levels of variables? Do you mean total number of variables? And what exactly do you mean by checking whether the coding has changed? Of course it has changed; those are two different programming languages, so the syntax *has* to change or it will fail to compile.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have just edited my question. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

not a hundred percent sure on your question. If it is "is there a way to compare amount of variables in project to see if coding has changed." I don't think there is a coding way in python to see how many of a specific type of variable are present in python